# OSRM docker premission denied

Tags: docker, debian, permissions, openstreetmap

Пытаюсь запустить https://hub.docker.com/r/osrm/osrm-backend/ из коробки

```
wget http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin-latest.osm.pbf
docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/berlin-latest.osm.pbf
```

и все выбрасывается ошибка

```
[root@sql2-dev osrm]# docker run -v "/opt/osrm:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p "/opt/car.lua" "/data/berlin-latest.osm.pbf"
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
[info] Parsed 0 location-dependent features with 0 GeoJSON polygons
[info] Using script /opt/car.lua
[info] Input file: berlin-latest.osm.pbf
[info] Profile: car.lua
[info] Threads: 1
[info] Parsing in progress..
[info] input file generated by osmium/1.8.0
[info] RAM: peak bytes used: 18042880
[error] Problem opening file: /data/berlin-latest.osrm.timestamp :  (possible cause: "Permission denied") (at include/storage/tar.hpp:38)
[root@sql2-dev osrm]#
```

Диагностирую вроде с правами все хорошо

```
[root@sql2-dev osrm]# ls -la
total 135176
drwxrwxrwx.  2 ashumeyko ashumeyko      120 Nov  5 14:51 .
drwxrwxrwx. 12 root      root           205 Nov  4 19:05 ..
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 ashumeyko ashumeyko 67198659 Nov  5 08:39 berlin-latest.osm.pbf
```

Глубокая диагностика и попытка запуска

```
docker run  -it --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend

root@cc0d1d00b34b:/data# cd /data
root@cc0d1d00b34b:/data# ls -la
total 135176
drwxrwxrwx. 2 1001 1001      120 Nov  5 09:51 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 1 root root       40 Nov  5 10:48 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 1001 1001 67198659 Nov  5 03:39 berlin-latest.osm.pbf
root@cc0d1d00b34b:/data#
```

В docker все прикрутилось пробую создать что ни будь:

```
root@cc0d1d00b34b:/data# touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied
```

Упс а тут непонятно что то что это значит как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как все не удивительно но ответ прост
отключить selinux

```
sudo setenforce 0
```